# ArgoCD feature branches deployment

Tags: argocd

I have one python API and Each time, I push a modification to a feature branch, I want it to be deployed. Each branch is deployed to its dedicated k8s namespace. Multiple branches can be active in the same time. To achieve that should I create a new ArgoCD application for each feature branch?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a [single ArgoCD application that points to a "template" Kubernetes manifest](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/tracking_strategies/) in your Git repository. When a new feature branch is created, you can override the parameters for this ArgoCD application to deploy to a new namespace. That could be automated using CI/CD pipelines.

It is easier to manage, as you have a single ArgoCD application. And it involves less duplication of ArgoCD application configurations.

But you will need to manage parameter overrides carefully. And it could become complex if feature branches have significant differences in their Kubernetes manifests.

Another option would be [ApplicationSets](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/): an ArgoCD extension that enables you to deploy multiple ArgoCD applications as defined by a generator. If your feature branches follow a naming convention, you can configure an ApplicationSet to automatically create a new ArgoCD application whenever a new branch is created.

That is highly automated and scalable. The Application management is simplified through the use of generators.

But it might be overkilled for simpler setups. And it requires an understanding of ApplicationSet generators.

Comment: thanks @Vonc.  applicationSet with pull request Generator fits my usecase

Comment: @DevOups Great, well done!